# How to get mobile phone numbers of a contact in a distribution list?

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get the mobile number of an Exchange contact that I found in a distribution list

`$result = Get-DistributionGroupMember Target-Group  | where{$_.externalemailAddress -eq "Target-Address"}`

`$result | select-object -property mobilephone`

It seems that unlike when using set-contact, mobilephone is not a property, so the last line will return nothing. $results has information, and if I cahnge mobilephone to phone I will get the target's work number, buut that isn't what I am looking for

Comment: This is from memory - I don't have a system available where I can test. As I recall, there's a Property hashtable that stores extended/custom properties of a contact. Try reviewing the `$result.Property` hashtable. Maybe you can get it from `$result.Property['mobilephone']` or something like that. If that fails, you may have to use `Get-Mailbox` on `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is no property called MobilePhone (there is one called Phone) using that cmdlet (I say this because I just checked all props for a user using it), unless you repurposed one of the CustomAttributes. So, you can use that to get the members, but you then have to call Get-ADUser or Get-ADObject to get that MobilePhone property.

Try this...

```
#Get a specific user object with the mobile property
Get-ADUser <username> -Properties MobilePhone
Get-ADObject -Filter { sAMAccountName -eq '' } -Properties MobilePhone
```

Or this...

```
#Get the members of a group and return their user object with the mobile property
Get-ADGroupMember <GroupName> | Get-ADUser -Properties mobile
```

So, for your use case, maybe something like this...

```
(
Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity '*' | 
Where-Object -Property RecipientType -EQ UserMailbox
).Name | 
ForEach { Get-ADUser -Identity $PSItem -Properties Name, MobilePhone }
```